# React Router, lifecycle when browser's back button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to detect when the user has hit the back button. Essentially, when a user goes from the /projects to /projects/foo the nav style changes.

```
<Route path="/projects" component={(props, state, params) => 
        <Projects {...props} />
</Route>
```

This works fine when detecting an onClick event from /projects to a specific project, but when the user hits the back button `componentDidMount` is not called... I'm trying to use `this.props.location.pathname` to determine the specific path, but as I need to set state I cannot do this inside `render`.

Is there a "react" way of going about this? Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, `componentDidMount` will only be called once when the component is mounted. Instead, use the lifecycle hook `componentWillReceiveProps`. [Here](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/component_will_receive_props.html) is the documentation.

You can use this to conditionally setState if you're at the desired/correct path. This will update the state which will then re-render the component.

UPDATE:

Since posting this answer `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated. You'll need to use `shouldComponentUpdate` or `getDerivedStateFromProps` depending on your use case. More info on that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).